# Competitive Types

Tags: assembly, struct

I have the following lines discovered in a piece of code (using IDA PRO) :

```
 ...
 ...
 push 44h
 pop edi
 push edi        ; size_t
 xor esi, esi
 lea eax, [ebp+StartupInfo]
 push esi        ; int 
 push eax        ; void *
 call _memset
 ...
 ...
```

When I saw the line **lea eax, [ebp+StartupInfo]** I thought, okay eax is a pointer to the structure STARTUPINFO. With int esi = 0 or NULL (see the line **xor esi, esi**) and with size_t edi = 44h and by calling memset, they must fill the first 44 bytes of STARTUPINFO (that would be the elements cb, lpReserved,....,wShowWindow).

But the line 
     push eax        ; void *

irritates me. How can eax has the type Startupinfo and void at the same time?

After that, I found out that the first parameter of memset()-function must have the type void. And so, the question mark in my mind is now bigger...

Comment: its the memset declaration, parameter is a size_to_memset (size_t), value to fill with (int), memory address (void*) and the void*, StartupInfo etc are all just high level concepts.. at the end of the day the chip doesnt care what it is, its just a number..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IDA knows that the prototype for the `_memset` function is `_memset(void *, int, size_t)`, so it's showing you that the value of `eax` in `push eax` is for the `void *` parameter.

However, later on in this function, a pointer to the `StartupInfo` structure is likely passed to `CreateProcess`, which is why IDA named it as such.

> How can eax has the type Startupinfo and void at the same time?

`eax` is just a register that holds a value, which in your disassembly above is the address of the `StartupInfo` structure. Types are high-level concepts, so when handled by `_memset`, the value of `eax` is interpreted as a `void *`, and when it's handled by `CreateProcess`, it's interpreted as a pointer to a `STARTUPINFO` structure.

Comment: thanks for your answer. The part " the value of eax is interpreted as a void *, and when it's handled by CreateProcess, it's interpreted as a pointer to a STARTUPINFO structure." was completely new for me. Thx!